# Fourier transform of power law with angular dependence

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For a simple power law function $$f(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{r^\alpha}\,,$$
it is well-known that its Fourier transform in $d$-dimensions is given by
$$\hat{f}(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{1}{k^{d-\alpha}}\,.$$.

Now consider the function $$f(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{r^\alpha} g(\Omega)$$

where $g(\Omega)$ is some dimensionless function of the angular coordinates. By simple dimensional analysis, it seems it must be the case that the Fourier transform is given by
$$\hat{f}(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{1}{k^{d-\alpha}} \hat{g}(\Omega_k)$$
for some function $\hat{g}(\Omega_k)$ of the angular coordinates in momentum space. Is there an explicit formula that relates $g(\Omega)$ to $\hat{g}(\Omega_k)$? I have been unable to derive such a relation.

Comment: Yes, you have to develop $g$ in *spherical harmonics*. The formula you are after can be found in the book "Introduction to harmonic analysis on Euclidean spaces" of E. Stein and G. Weiss, there is a chapter devoted to it. Or if you like physical notation better, try searching for "plane wave expansion", that's another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Great, thanks, that's helpful. I was aware of spherical harmonics roughly being the equivalent of a Fourier transform in angular coordinates, but wasn't aware that they could be nicely decomposed as such in this case.

Comment: Cool, happy it helped. If you find the result and you have the time, I would love to see it, you may considering writing an answer to your own question. I would upvote it for sure.

Comment: I would guess something like this. If $g(\Omega)=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty Y_\ell(\Omega), $ where $Y_\ell$ is a spherical harmonic of degree $\ell$, then the Fourier transform of $\frac1{r^\alpha} g(\Omega)$ should be $$\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{d-\alpha-\ell}} Y_\ell(\Omega).$$ Something like this.

Comment: That general form doesn't look quite right by dimensional analysis - since $r$ has units of length and $k$ has units of inverse length, the Fourier transform should be fixed to scale as $\frac{1}{k^{d-\alpha}}$ dimensionally. Stein and Weiss's book is turning out to be very useful, although working out all the details is a bit tricky as formally defining Fourier transforms of power laws generally comes with convergence issues. Will type up an answer if/when I have a better answer.

Comment: I like how Terry Tao computes the Fourier transform of the power function [in his lecture notes on distributions](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/#hatk) (start reading from the string "Let us work formally at first, and consider the problem of computing the Fourier transform of the function"). Hope this is interesting for you.